# Using YUI with Spring framework

Tags: spring, yui

i am new to ajax technology
and i want to use YUI technology with spring framework
so please guide me where to start;useful links & tutorials
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUI is a Javascript library.  Spring is a Java application framework.  These are not directly related; ie, Spring has no YUI hooks or anything like that.

[Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html) and [Spring Web Flow](http://www.springsource.org/webflow) can be used to build web applications, and web applications can serve whatever files you want, including any Javascript files you have.

Here is a list of [YUI examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/).

Answer (score 0):

YUI is a client side js library, and has little to do with serverside frameworks; so, Spring and YUI are not related.

if your are looking to work with [YUI2](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/), or for [YUI3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/). also [yui-gallery](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/) is a good place to get started with the [examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/).

[YUI Theater](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/) has a whole bunch of developer videos to help you understand the internals of YUI JS Library, is a place worth spending time